# Where to handle IOException when adding a file handler to a logger in a class?

Tags: java, logging

I am trying to set up a logging system for my application.

I have seen [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/logging/write-log-entries-to-log-file/) that it is possible to send logs to an individual file. The code is as follows:

```java
package com.javacodegeeks.snippets.core;

import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class WriteLogEntriesToLogFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        boolean append = true;
        FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("default.log", append);

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.javacodegeeks.snippets.core");
        logger.addHandler(handler);

        logger.severe("severe message");

        logger.warning("warning message");

        logger.info("info message");

        logger.config("config message");

        logger.fine("fine message");

        logger.finer("finer message");

        logger.finest("finest message");

    }

}
```

In my case, I would like to add this logging to a Class. I attach a basic class and what I have tried (the class is a singleton, so that fact is included in the example):

```java
public class MyClass {

    FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("MyClass.log", false);
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());

    // SINGLETON PATTERN
    private static final MyClass SINGLE_INSTANCE = new MyClass();         
    private MyClass() {
    }
    public static MyClass getInstance() {
      return SINGLE_INSTANCE;
    }    

    public void doStuff() {

        Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.FINE, "Log Text");

    }

}
```

But I get:

1. In `FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("OrderFlowDrawer.log", false);`: unreported IOException.
2. In `Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());`: the logger declaration shall be static and final.

From that I have the following questions/doubts I can not fully understand:

1. How shall I handle the IOException?
2. Why the logger declaration shall be static and final?

I am using Java 8 in case it could be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How shall I handle the IOException?

This is a good question and there are many different answers.  I often still use `System.err.println(...)` to report just these sorts of issues.  Specifically initialization issues where the logging subsystem, configuration, or other startup operations have failed.  This means that when I run my application, there is still some sort of console.log.  This also works to capture the rare JVM fault or message emitted by poorly behaving 3rd party software to stderr.

This means that if the application fails fast because of some sort of bootstrap issue, I go looking in the `console.log` to see if there is any information there.  This also means that I should emit `"System is running"` type of message to the `console.log` so I know when to switch to looking at my logging files instead of the console if there are problems.

If the `Logger` constructor throws `IOException`, then for `static` fields, I catch and rethrow the exception as a `RuntimeException`.  Something like:

```
private static final Logger;

// this static black is executed before the class constructor and is the way
// that I initialize static fields that throw exceptions
static {
   try {
      logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
   } catch (IOExcepion ioe) {
      System.err.println("Initialization of logger threw");
      ioe.printStackTrace();
      // this will cause the class to not initialize and typically brings down the JVM
      throw new RuntimeException("Initialization of logger threw", ioe);
   }
}
```

> Why the logger declaration shall be static and final?

`static` fields are shared between multiple instances of a class.  Typically if you have multiple `MyClass` instances, they should share the same instance of the logger and not have one per class instance.  That said, once and a while I *do* want a per-class-instance logger because I want to separate the logging prefix, but it is rare.

`final` may be important, depending on the logger implementation in terms of ensuring that the logging class is fully initialized before it is used in terms of thread memory sharing.  `final` fields must be fully constructed and the compiler is not able to delay their initialization.  Given that the logger may be used by multiple threads, this is important.  `final` also ensures that some misbehaving part of the code doesn't change the value of the logger or set it to `null`.  Different parts of your classes will be relying on the logger field having a value and don't want to have to do `if (logger != null) ...` type patterns everywhere.

Comment: Netbeans actually forces you to capture the IOException somewhere, it is an error and the Class won't compile. Inside a method, I understand that you can either throw the exception or capture it with a try and catch. Shall the assignment of the logger be moved to the constructor and inserted in a try/catch block? Otherwise I do not know how to do it

Comment: I've added a segment about that to my answer @M.E.

Comment: Thanks the addition helps to better understand how to use Logging.